# How to get the inside dimensions of a decorated window in XWindows?

Tags: c++, c, border, x11, window-decoration

If I create a full screen window where **m_winw** and **m_winh** is the full screen size, it seems to create a window for me where the outside dimension is the full screen and the inside is smaller based on the **"decoration"** (window border) size. Is there a way to query the window to get it's inside width and height?

```
m_win=XCreateWindow(m_display, m_rootwin, m_winx, m_winy, m_winw, m_winh, 0, 
CopyFromParent,CopyFromParent,m_visual,CWColormap|CWEventMask,&attributes);
```

This is on linux.

Answer (score 1):

See XGetWindowAttributes, XGetGeometry.  According to the man page:

> The width and height members are set tothe inside size of the window, not including the border.